# Detecting and deleting alpha mark in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, rgb

I got a couple of 4 band images, band 1-3 is RGB and band 4 is NIR.   [image: Bands 1-4]

In the properties it says nothing about an alpha mark, does that mean that none of them is marked as alpha channel or how do I detect an alpha channel (and if there's one, how can I remove it)?

Comment: The alpha band is used for transparency. So if your 4 bands are composed of 3 RGBs and 1 NIR, there should be no alpha band associated with it.

Comment: @Joseph thanks for your explanation.
I just checked the info you get, when opening an image with preview on MAC and there it says _Alpha:1_

Answer (score 1):

If you need, you can use *Rearrange bands* algorythm.

[image]

You can remove band 4, and you will have 3 band rgb raster without alpha channel.

Comment: not working. alpha channel is still there.